# Why does it give a "multiple test case" error?

Tags: c++

I've written the code for eliminating the largest 2 elements of an array, but this code gives junk value for `testcase > 1`. Why?

Input:

```
no of TestCase
size of array
elements of array
```

Sorting function:

```
int sort_asc(int arr[], int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
        for(int j=i+1;j<n;j++)
        {
            if(arr[j]<arr[i])
            {
                int temp;
                temp=arr[i];
                arr[i]=arr[j];
                arr[j]=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}

int main() {
    //code
    int test;
    cin>>test;
    while(test--){
        //taking size and array as inputs
        int size;
        cin>>size;
        int a[size];
        cin>>a[size];
        for(int i=0;i<size;i++){
            cin>>a[i];
        }
        //sorting the array
        sort_asc(a,size);
        //printing the output discarding last 2 elements of the array
        for(int i=0;i<size-2;i++){
            cout<<a[i]<<" ";
        }
        cout<<"\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Expected:

```
12 23 28 43 44 59 60 68 70 85 88 92 124 125 136 168 171 173 179 199 212 
230 277 282 306 314 316 325 328 336 337 363 365 368 369 371 374 387 394 414 
422 427 430 435 457 493 506 527 531 538 541 546 568 583 650 691 730 737 751 
764 778 783 785 789 794 803 809 815 847 858 863 874 887 896 916 920 926 927  930 957
```

My output:

```
12 23 28 43 44 59 60 68 70 81 85 88 92 124 125 136 168 171 173 179 199  212 230 277 282 306 314 316 325 328 336 337 363 365 368 369 371 374 387 394 414 422 427 430 435 457 493 506 527 531 538 541 546 568 583 650 691 730 737 751 764 778 783 785 789 794 803 809 815 847 858 863 874 887 896 916 920 926 930 957
```

Answer (score 0):

A VLA (variable length array) is invalid C++ code. It is tolerated by some compilers, but it is still invalid.

But that is not your main problem. You produced an out of bound error. An array index starts with 0. The last element is at position size-1. So your statement

`cin>>a[size];`

will write past the end of your array. Producing undefined behavior.

I am not sure, why you put the statement at all, but after that, anything undefined can and most probably will happen.